# How should I configure /etc/host.allow on OpenBSD to only allow given IP's?

Tags: openbsd, openbsd-httpd

I have an OpenBSD 5.1 box that is running a static html based website.

I have a list of IP addresses that I want to allow, ex.:

```
...
78.128.49.0/24
78.128.50.0/24
...
```

It's a ~10 KByte. ~10 000 lines. I only want to allow these IP addresses, not else to contact the server (httpd, ssh, anything, even ports that aren't used).

***Q***: What is the best syntax to do this in the host.allow/host.deny file? (AFAIK it should be better to put 10 000 IP address ranges in a file then puting them in the firewall..)

Comment: Are enough of these addresses/nets contiguous to consolidate them?  For example, 78.128.50.0/24 and 78.128.51.0/24 = 78.128.50.0/23

Comment: Just for my own curiosity, what are your issues with putting the rules into the firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With OpenBSD's implementation of `tcpwrappers`, I think you need to include each of your addresses in `/etc/hosts.allow`, which, with 10k entries, will very soon get very unwieldy.

```
ALL : ... 78.128.49.0/24 78.128.50.0/24 ... : deny
```

It won't take many lines before this becomes a nightmare to manage. Note that addresses are separated with spaces or commas, or both.

If you have `pf` configured and running, you might find it easier to populate a table from the contents of your address file:

```
table <blockthese> persist file /etc/list-of-addresses-to-block

block in log quick on $ext_if from <blockthese> to any
```

Lookups against tables in `pf` are quick, and tables are pretty efficient in terms of memory use, so unless you have really limited amounts of RAM on an old machine, this should work just fine - it's a strategy I use on numerous FreeBSD hosts, and it works very well.